# Button clicks are not working in Samsung device having Os 10 or more

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, buttonclick

I have a layout with a video view, which occupies the whole screen and few buttons, ImageViews, and layouts over it. When the video reaches some point(some secs), I make the eventNote layout visible and pause the video. I have a close button in the Evernote layout, then click on the close button, I make the eventNote layout visibility gone and resume the video, from where it stops. Everything works in all the devices, except Samsung devices with OS 10 or more. Video plays, the layout visibility works, but the buttons and images over the video view are not clickable. Only on Samsung devices. Other devices having Os 10 or more works fine. I couldn't find out what's happening.
**XML file:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/layoutVideoPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layBack"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnBack"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/back_arrow" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.mypackage.utils.FontTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEventTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layBack"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_20"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/camera_icon_white" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnBackward"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnForward"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/backward_icon"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnForward"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/forward_icon"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnZoom"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/laySeekbar"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/speed_icon"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/seekBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/seekbar_layout_background">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/playButton"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:src="@drawable/pause_icon" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/raceEndImage"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/raceEndImage"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/playButton"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/playButton"
                android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:progressTint="@color/white"
                android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/raceEndImage"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:src="@drawable/flag_pin_icon" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout

            android:id="@+id/laySeekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


            <com.mypackage.utils.MyScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layLandmarks"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/viewWhite"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@color/white" />


                </RelativeLayout>
            </com.mypackage.utils.MyScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/laySeekbarText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnCircle"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <com.mypackage.utils.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/seekBarProgressValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"

                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_15" />

            <com.mypackage.utils.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtVideoElevationValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seekBarProgressValue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_15"
                android:visibility="gone"

                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/btnCircle"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
            android:background="@color/grey" />

        <include layout="@layout/event_notes_layout" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/lay_screenshot"
            android:layout_above="@+id/laySeekbarText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/lay_water_station"
            android:layout_above="@+id/laySeekbarText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/lay_first_aid"
            android:layout_above="@+id/laySeekbarText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
           />




    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutVideoScreenShot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/black_transparent_background"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <com.mypackage.utils.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="New Screenshot taken at 7.1mi"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_18" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgScreenshot"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/layBottomView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtHeader"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/black" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layBottomView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.mypackage.utils.FontEditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtDesc"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:hint="@string/add_desc"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <com.mypackage.utils.FontTextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtMakePublic"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/make_public"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <ToggleButton
                            android:id="@+id/toggleMakePublic"
                            android:layout_width="35dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
                            android:textOff=""
                            android:textOn=""
                            android:visibility="gone" />


                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <com.mypackage.utils.FontTextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtVisibleOnMap"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/visible_on_map"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <ToggleButton
                            android:id="@+id/toggleVisibleOnMap"
                            android:layout_width="35dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
                            android:textOff=""
                            android:textOn=""
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinner"
                            style="@style/SpinnerStyle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <com.mypackage.utils.FontTextView
                            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/divider"
                            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                            android:text="@string/save"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_15" />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/divider"
                            android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:layout_height="10dp"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnCancel"
                            android:background="@color/black" />

                        <com.mypackage.utils.FontTextView
                            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                            android:text="@string/cancel"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_15" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/videoProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I dont understand the question bro